# How to figure out where the AJAX request is being sent?

Tags: javascript, ajax, frontend, fetch, google-chrome-devtools

Using Chrome Dev Tools, how do you find where (what URL or serer) your AJAX request is being sent to?

I use Chrome Dev Tools -> Network tab -> All or XHR.
I view the headers and the responses of AJAX requests, but I can't figure out how to find where the AJAX requests are going?

If not with Chrome's Dev Tools, is there another tool? Is there any way to figure this out?

Comment: Test comment...

Comment: simple - Network tab

Answer (score 1):

The first column in the network tab, the `name`, contains the destination. Hover over the name of one of the rows to see the full path.

For the example below, I posted a test comment on this question, and in Chrome devtools, I can see that the XHR request was to the endpoint `https://stackoverflow.com/posts/66510503/comments`.

[image]

You can also look at the `:path` in the Request Headers.

You can also right click the name, go to *Copy*, and press *Copy link address* to get it on your clipboard.

Comment: stack overflow doesn't allow selecting the best answer within 10 mins apparently, I'll get back on later and award you the best answer!